# add attribute to signature xml in java

Tags: xml, digital-signature

I need to add an ID attribute to the root element in my signature XML block, using java. Here is the current signature XML file:

```
<ds:Signature>
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>36FmAjgxR3feEHGoblPJz1IWyTM=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509SubjectName>...</ds:X509SubjectName>
        <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

But i need to add an attribute like:

`<ds:Signature ID="SOMETHING">`

Comment: but that would not generate me that this signature is not consistent with the XML document?  ... here my classes

Answer (score 2):

The solution

XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, Ki,null,"SignST",null);